# Haskell and/or Clojure

Tags: haskell, concurrency, clojure, functional-programming

I'm looking to expand my knowledge of programming languages and I keep looking at both Haskell and Clojure to learn.

So far I have spent a day with each and I am leaning towards Haskell as I find it somewhat easier for me to use, at least after a day of using each.

General Questions:

- What are the use cases of Haskell and Clojure?
- What problems / uses are suited best for these languages?
- What problems are functional programming languages better for?

What I am looking to do:

- I want to write a concurrent / scalable web server or application in
  one of these languages, which would be the best suited for the task?
- Find a functional language I can add to my list of languages.

Comment: Based on your goals, I would suggest Clojure. It is definently concurrent, used in ClojureScript, and is an upcoming and *largely growing* language.

Comment: @Zchpyvr: Haskell is also highly concurrent, and has powerful web frameworks (Snap and Yesod). Also, it seems to be more popular: http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html

Comment: Both are great. Haskell is more elegant/pure. Clojure is best for getting things done. But not really a good fit for a SO question, so voting to close, sorry.

Comment: Haskell being more elegant is arguable. More pure is true.

Comment: Learn enough of both to be comfortable reading/writing them! They have different goals and are different paradigms (looking beyond the "functional" umbrella).